# Is it actually safer to use self signed certificate than trusted certificate in the case of custom client software?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I am very new to HTTPS and SSL certificates.

Based on my short experience, I managed to create trusted SSL certificates for my domain name using FREE certbot generation.

Now using this trusted FREE certificate, I am able to access my site without even needing to trust it manually. When I create a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL, browsers will forbid me from accessing unless I manually trust the certificate.

In my case, I am not allowing normal Web Browsers for my website but the website is supposed to be only accessible from a specific client software.

Based on the above information, I have a feeling that a self-signed certificate is actually safer than the trusted one, since the client software will trust my self-signed one anyway and why not add an additional protection to prevent other browsers from accessing my webpage.

On the other hand, I am pretty sure my feeling is wrong and a self-signed certificate cannot be safer than the trusted one. However I couldn't figure out where my above logic is wrong.

I also couldn't understand why payed SSL certificates exists as I can generate a free trusted one using certbot, and I have a feeling maybe it is the same point I am missing for trusted vs. self-signed certificates.

Comment: *"I also couldn't understand why payed SSL certificates exists as I can generate a free trusted one using certbot"* [What’s the Difference Between DV, OV, IV, and EV Certificates?](https://www.ssl.com/article/dv-ov-and-ev-certificates/) Free ones are DV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users are going to be using your own software to access your website, then there is no difference between a trusted certificate or a self-signed certificate. Though, using a self-signed certificate does not guarantee that users using other browsers cannot access it. Many popular browsers such as Chrome allow a user to continue to a site with a non-trusted certificate. You can use either, but make sure your software can access it.

Comment: So there is no difference between free and payed certificate either, am I correct?

Comment: If your users will use your own software, you are correct